# Installing a grab bar into a cinder block/plaster walls

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures

I need to install a grab bar for my mother in her shower. It will need to hold up to 250 to 300 pounds. My concern is the house is cinder block and plaster. I don't even know if there is a hollow part to the cinder block. Do I need to drill an area where the bar will go to find out? Assuming there is no hollow part, what would be an appropriate anchor or fastener to install the grab bar?

Comment: Far better to land in the solid part, strength-wise. But it's probably going to be random chance unless you can see the outlines of the blocks.

Comment: I have to go through tile first. I just know there is block behind it and no clue if there is any sort of cavity, but I doubt there is.

Comment: What's on the other side of the wall?

Comment: How is the shower built?  Concrete block, with studs, then cement backer board and tile?  Something else?

Comment: I don't know. Every wall I have seen past the plaster seems to just be cinder block. I haven't seen a stud anywhere. Would there definitely be some? The walls are cinder block with plaster over them.

Comment: The other side of the wall is a bedroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these screw/anchor combos and use it to attach the bar. I can't find a pic but it's basically a screw with really large thread. I drilled a pilot hole a bit smaller than the screw and screwed the bar on. It seems really sturdy right now. I really only need it to last about 2 years while we save up for a full remodel. Based on the drilling I did, it doesn't seem like there is a hollow part, in the shower, but the the grab bar is close to the edge, so it's likely that I didn't drill far enough from the front to be past the thickness of  the brick.